# Maven does not find dependencies, eclipse works correctly, with ca.uhn.hapi.fhir dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, dependencies

i'm working on a Java project that works correctly in Eclipse. When i use another IDE, or when i try to compile it using maven, i have some compilation errors, all related to a specific import.
In pom, i have:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-fhir-structures-dstu3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The library is correctly imported and i can use some libraries that are in the package ca.uhn.hapi....

In some points of the code, i use this class:

```
org.hl7.fhir.exceptions.FHIRException;
```

So, the problem is: when i compile using eclipse, it works correctly. The class org.hl7.fhir.exceptions.FHIRException; is correctly imported and used. When i compile using maven (mvn install), i have this error:

```
.java:[5,31] package org.hl7.fhir.exceptions does not exist
```

It sounds like the package is not imported correctly. I think that eclipse does some automatic operations to import code correctly.
Another particular thing is that  org.hl7.fhir.exceptions is contained into ca.uhn.hapi.fhir. The directory structure is:

```
.m2\repository\ca\uhn\hapi\fhir\org.hl7.fhir.utilities\5.2.0\org.hl7.fhir.utilities-5.2.0.jar
```

And this classes are in package org.hl7.fhir.exceptions;

Is there a way to fix that issue? How can Eclipse recognize that i'm importing a package X, that is contained in a pom with a completely different name? (org.hl7 VS ca.uhn)

Comment: The maven-dependency you listed has ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-utilities:3.2.0, not 5.2.0 that you looked for in the local mvn-repo. 3.2.0 also contains that class, that is not the problem. But if you're looking for different versions of the same set of dependencies, something else might be happening in your pom that influences dependency-version-resolution - which can cause all kinds of ClassNot, NoSuchMethod, ... errors

Comment: If you build on command line does not work... there is a problem in your build doesn't matter if Eclipse works (or look like working..) Do you have a link to that project? Apart from that is there a good reason why you using an old version of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It was a trivial maven repository problem. For some reasons, this was a bug caused by a maven repository cache error. I deleted the repository folder (.m2/repository) and downloaded again dependencies... Very strange because the files were the same.